# The most efficient way to display a tutorial containing only images

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

I am developing an app that will show a quick tutorial in the begining containing about 7 images  in case it is the first time the user has installed the app.

At first I had created 7 fragments, one for each image. 
The fragments would be be displayed at the **Tutorial Activity**.
This activity would contain a button called "Learn More" that would display the next fragment, replacing the current one.

I know that this is the only part of the app that this images and sequences will be displayed and I don't intend to let the user go backwards (it won't be possible to show the previous image in case he already hit "Learn more").

That being said, would not it be more efficient in terms of memory if I just used a LinearLayout containing an ImageView and every time the button "Learn More" is clicked, the next image would be displayed?

So.. instead of:

```
Fragment1  -> Displays Image1
Fragment2  -> Displays Image2
Fragment3  -> Displays Image3
Fragment4  -> Displays Image4
Fragment5  -> Displays Image5
Fragment6  -> Displays Image6
Fragment7  -> Displays Image7
```

...would not it be more efficient:

```
-LinearLayout containing an ImageView
-Button to change ImageView to the next Image
```

Thank you.

Comment: What about `ViewPager`. Swipe left and right functionality. Simple and fancy.

Comment: I am not familiar with ViewPager. I will do some research in order to learn about it.

Comment: One advice: don't set the tuto images in Background of some Layout, it will explode the bitmap memory

Comment: Good move. You should learn it. Its good.

Comment: Use `ViewFlipper` instead